# Excel - Relatórios

Tags: microsoft-excel

Bom dia, tenho feito relatórios no excel em que tanto eu como o meu cliente introduzimos dados no mesmo.
Gostaria da vossa ajuda para saber como fazer por forma que tanto eu como o cliente não introduzimos um dado que já se encontra inserido no relatório, por forma a evitar repetições em apenas uma coluna do mesmo.

Obrigada

Comment: Snarne, bom dia! Qual a complexidade desse relatório? Pois poderia utilizar uma ferramenta on-line que poderiam editar os dois juntos, ao mesmo tempo e vendo se o outro está on-line e o que está fazendo. Teste e veja se te atende o Google Drive[http://drive.google.com]. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Bem vindo(a) ao SOPt. Se não fez ainda, por favor leia a [help] e, principalmente, [ask]. Tenho certeza que muitos outros gostariam de ajudar, assim como eu, mas você precisa fornecer detalhes da sua dificuldade. Este site não é um fórum. Por favor, edite a pergunta para incluir um exemplo (se possível visual) de que tipo de dado é esse, onde ele se encontra, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Método 1 - Use "Remover duplicatas" (MS Office)

Se você já tem dados duplicados basta você selecionar a área e procurar **Dados** > **Ferramenta de Dados** > **Remover duplicatas** ([tutorial](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Filtrar-valores-exclusivos-ou-remover-valores-duplicados-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2))

### Método 2 - Use "Filtro padrão" (Libreoffice/OpenOffice)

1. primeiro clique em qualquer parte dentro da tabela (ex.: A1)
2. vá no menu **Dados** > item **Mais filtros** > item **Filtro padrão** >

Agora preencha o formulário:

- em **Nome do campo** selecione `- nenhum -`
- pressione o sinal de mais ao lado de opções `[+] Opções`
- marque `[x] Sem duplicatas`
- pressione `[   OK   ]`

### Método 3 - Ordene uma coluna ou ordene por "linhas"

**Quando uma só coluna não pode ser duplicada**

Uma solução bem simples é deixar uma de suas colunas sempre ordenada (a que não pode ser duplicada por exemplo), para isso coloque o [autofiltro](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/In%C3%ADcio-r%C3%A1pido-classificar-dados-usando-um-AutoFiltro-do-Excel-Starter-b8906a6a-bb20-4a05-ade7-8da1e9db69e9?omkt=pt-BR&ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR).

**Ordenar por "linhas"**

Muitas vezes as pessoas projetam mal o modelo de dados em uma planilha colocando dados que se repetem nela (isso deve ser separado em outra planilha).

Mas se isso acontece, não tem outro jeito a não ser encontrar uma forma de ordenar as "linhas".

Vamos supor um caso bem simples:

```
nome  gosta_de  horario
ana   nadar     8
ana   caminhar  7
ana   nadar     6
ana   nadar     8
joao  caminhar  9
```

Maneira errada de fazer a planilha: o campo "horario" está fazendo todos os outros duplicarem (nome e gosta_de). Ou coloca o horário em outra planilha, ou a coluna "horário" deveria ter todos os horários (por ex., separados por vírgula, espaço etc.). O melhor seria adotar um campo como chave primária (o nome se repete? use RG). Na tabela acima você deve ter percebido que uma entrada foi duplicada (a 1ª **ana nadar 8** foi duplicada na 4ª linha)

#### Método 4 - Soluções externas

Mesmo assim não conseguiu?

No Windows (no Unix/Linux melhor ainda!) se você salvar sua planilha em CSV você pode usar ferramentas bem práticas na linha de comando, suponho que você esteja no Windows (instruções abaixo valem só para quem tem Windows XP SP2 em diante):

1. salve a planilha em *c:\planilha.csv*
2. pressione `Ctrl+R` e digite `powershell`
3. agora digite: `gc c:\planilha.csv | sort | get-unique > c:\planilha2.csv`
4. abra o arquivo *planilha2.csv* que ele estará sem as duplicações

**Nota**: essa última solução só vai ser interessante se você estiver separando os dados da lógica da aplicação (ex.: colocar uma planilha para os dados e outra para colocar funções Excel que usam esses dados).

Answer (score 0):

Há varias formas de resolver, eu apresento uma forma sem muita sofisticação, mas que pode ser adaptada para a sua necessidade.

A planilha abaixo mostra um exemplo de como fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Coluna A** = Seus dados digitados, neste caso de A1 a A9

**Colna B** = Número da linha, neste caso vai até a linha 91 (ver fórmulas abaixo)

**Coluna C** = Número da linha de ocorrência da primeira repetição do dado da mesma linha

**Início**: são as células iniciais referentes às colunas A e C (você deve informar)

**Final**: são apresentadas automaticamente, no caso da célula E2, B91 indica a última célula da coluna B que contém o número de linhas preparadas para receberem dados (linha 91). No caso da célula F2, a última célula da coluna C que corresponde ao número de linha até onde os dados foram digitados (linha 9).

**Repetições**: quantidade de repetições encontradas (somente a primeira ocorrência de cada dado). Veja no caso da letra C que ela aparece repetida duas vezes, o C da linha 3 aponta a primeira repetição na linha 6, enquanto o C da linha 6 aponta a segunda repetição na linha 7.

**Conteúdo das células**:

Células coluna A:

Dados digitados

Células coluna B (em todas até o limite que desejar):

=LIN()

Células coluna C:

=SE(ÉERROS(PROCV(A1;INDIRETO("A"&(LIN()+1)&":B"&$E$2);1;FALSO));"";PROCV(A1;INDIRETO("A"&(LIN()+1)&":B"&$E$2);2;FALSO))

Célula E1:

Digite a célula inicial dos dados, neste exemplo: A1

Célula F1

Digite a célula inicial das ocorrências de repetições, neste exemplo: C1

Célula E2

="B"&MÁXIMO(B1:B9999)

Célula F2

="C"&CONT.SE(A1:A9999;">''")

Célula E4

=CONT.SE(INDIRETO(F1&":"&F2);">0")

Uma sugestão é fazer a célula E4 receber uma formatação condicional, a de ficar com o fundo vermelho e o número em amarelo caso o valor dela seja maior do que zero. Isso chamará a atenção, como também as células da coluna C receberem esta condição, ao digitar com duplicação, aparecerá o número da linha repetido em amarelo com fundo vermelho.

Espero ter ajudado!